# DownloadFIleCompleted and DownloadProgressChanged not firing in a multithread win forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, webclient

I'm having a problem using the `WebClient` events in a multi threaded application (`DownloadFileCompleted` and `DownloadProgressChanged`).
I have the main method in which I created a timer. At an interval, I will create a thread that will popup another windows form (`DownloaderForm`) if a condition is met.

```
void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    var thread = new Thread(SilentCheckingUpdate) {
        Name = "Update Checker",
    };
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}
```

The SilentChekingUpdate method checks for update.

```
bool found = _updater.UpdateRequired(currentConfig, out latestVersion);

if (found)
{
    _updater.ShowUpdateUI(latestVersion); 
}
```

If found, it calls another method from win forms class Updater which calss the StartDownload from Downloader.

```
public void ShowUpdateUI(Item currentItem)
{
    var downloader = new Downloader();
    downloader.StartDownload();
}
```

The downloader contains an WebBrowserControl. I made a method that calls DownloadFileAsync.

```
public void StartDownload()
{          
    // start async download
    var client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadProgressChanged += ClientDownloadProgressChanged;
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += ClientDownloadFileCompleted;
    var url = new Uri(_item.DownloadLink);

    client.DownloadFileAsync(url, _tempName);
}
```

Everything works fine and events are fired if I call that StartDownload function from the form thread. When i use the worker thread for StartDownload from TimerElapsed, DownloadFileAsync's events are not fired anymore.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be wrong when you don't provide code that shows the problem.  You say you have a problem with the StartDownload from a worker thread from TimerElapsed but you don't provide code that calls StartDownload from the thread created in TimerElapsed.

Comment: I edited the post with more info. Thank you for your time, Peter!

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why you're starting a thread that basically just calls `DownloadFileAsync`--which downloads a file async.  If `DownloadFileAsync` is async, there's not much reason to start another thread to call it.

One think I would look at is that you're creating a local `client` object in your `StartDownload` method.  This almost immediately lets `client` go out of scope and potentially lets the GC collect it.  If that happened, it could lead to problems.  *Maybe* making `client` a member field might help; but, that's a guess.

You haven't provided the code "that works*, so it's really hard to tell why there's a difference.

Comment: I started a thread because i was getting an eroor from WebBrowser control like: "ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment."

Comment: You main thread *must* be STA if you want to use ActiveX controls on you forms.  When you create a Windows Forms application the main thread is by default STA (STAThread on Program.Main).  If you've changed that, that's why you'd get that error.  If you haven't changed that, then you've created another thread that's calling WebBrowser.

Comment: WebBrowser can only be used on an STA thread and only on a thread that has a message pump.  i.e. a UI thread.

Comment: You are probably right. It is possible that the timer object is using another thread?

Comment: Yes, System.Timers.Timer uses another thread.  You should be using System.Forms.Timer if you want to do anything with any controls in the `Tick` Handler